# Most Compact Way to Write A List Of Integers to A File In Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an NumPy array of integers:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=300_000_000)
```

I want to write this array to a file (machine readable is fine) so that the file is as small as possible and then it will be read back into memory at a later time. What is the most compact way to write/read this array to a file?

I've tried:

```
x.astype('int16').tofile('file.int16')  # 572 MB
df.to_csv("file.csv", index=False, header=None)  # 1.1 GB
df.to_parquet("file.parq", index=False, compression="GZIP")  # 556M
```

Please show both the writing of the file, the reading of the file, and the file size for the array shown above.

Comment: `numpy.savez_compressed` might be slightly smaller (not much probably) ... real non random data might also compress down further

Comment: Generally `np.save` is nearly the best.  It is, essentially, a byte copy of the array's data buffer (with a small parameter buffer).